# Connecting to Oracle from SqlDeveloper

Tags: oracle

While am connecting to Oracle database from SQLDeveloper, am getting this error "`Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.`" But am able to connect to the database from SQL command promt. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Make sure while connecting through SqlDeveloper you are entering the correct configuration such as hostname, port, sid if your connection type : Basic.
Otherwise you can also try through Connection type : tns

Comment: Please describe the exact steps you are using to connect. When you connect from sqlplus are you specifying the database with @ which you indicate the the network listener is working correctly?

Comment: Giving everything like(hostname, port, sid) correct. And when i search over the web am seeing results like jdk issue.

Answer (score 0):

may be several problems

- The database isn't running
- You got the URL wrong
- There is a firewall in the way